# How to plot a map of a semi-sphere (eg northern hemisphere) using matplotlib cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

How to plot a map of a semi-sphere (eg northern hemisphere) using cartopy.

I'm trying to plot a map of the northern hemisphere using cartopy. But I don't understand how should I define the extent of the map so that only this region of interest is plotted. I would like the map to be cut off at 0° latitude. I would like to have code where I could easily define any subset of the glob using the ccrs.NearsidePerspective projection, or the ccrs.Orthographic projection.

Below I leave a code for reproduction.

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating fake data
x = np.linspace(-180, 180, 361)
y = np.linspace(-90, 90, 181)
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(x, y)
values = np.random.random(lon.shape)*20


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))

proj = ccrs.NearsidePerspective(central_longitude=-45, central_latitude=21)

ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection=proj)
ax.set_extent([-120, 40, 0, 60])

ax.pcolormesh(lon, lat, values, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines(linewidth=2)
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linestyle='--')
```

The code generates the following figure:
[image]
Thank you very much in advance.
Robson

Comment: The extent of the figure is currently correct. But because of your projection you can see other parts of the world. Setting the axis extent doesn’t mask your data. To do that, you could do something along the lines of `values =np.where(lat > 0, values, np.nan)`

Comment: @MichaelDelgado 
Thank you very much for your comment. The answer below answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot only the upper hemisphere part of the map projection, a polygon of that part is needed to use as the projection boundary.

That polygon is created as a matplotlib-path object. It vertices' coordinates are data coordinates in my code, so that, no transformation is required when applied to the final plot.

This is a complete code:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12, 12])
proj = ccrs.NearsidePerspective(central_longitude=-45, central_latitude=21, satellite_height=35785831)
ax = plt.subplot(projection=proj)

# The value of r is obtained by previous run of this code ...
#  with the line .. #print(ax.get_xlim()) uncommented
r = 5476336.098
ax.set_xlim(-r, r)
ax.set_ylim(-r, r)

ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines(lw=1, color="darkblue")

# Find the locations of points along the equatorial arc
# start location
lon_fr, lat_fr = 30, 0
# end location
lon_to, lat_to = -120, 0

# This gets geodesic between the two points, WGS84 ellipsoid is used
geodl = Geodesic.WGS84.InverseLine(lat_fr, lon_fr, lat_to, lon_to)

lonlist, latlist = [], []
num_points = 32  #for series of points on geodesic/equator
for ea in np.linspace(0, geodl.s13, num_points):
    g = geodl.Position(ea, Geodesic.STANDARD | Geodesic.LONG_UNROLL)
    #print("{:.0f} {:.5f} {:.5f} {:.5f}".format(g['s12'], g['lat2'], g['lon2'], g['azi2']))
    lon2, lat2 = g['lon2'], g['lat2']
    lonlist.append( g['lon2'] )
    latlist.append( g['lat2'] )

# Get data-coords from (lonlist, latlist)
# .. as points along equatorial arc
dataxy = proj.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), np.array(lonlist), np.array(latlist))

# (Uncomment to) Plot equator line
#ax.plot(dataxy[:, 0:1], dataxy[:, 1:2], "go-", linewidth=2, markersize=5, zorder=10)

# Top semi-circle arc for map extent
theta = np.linspace(-0.5*np.pi, 0.5*np.pi, 64)
center, radius = [0, 0], r
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T

# Combine vertices of the semi-circle and equatorial arcs
# These points are in data coordinates, ready to plot on the axes.
verts = np.vstack([verts*r, dataxy[:, 0:2]])

polygon = mpath.Path(verts + center)
ax.set_boundary(polygon) #This masks-out unwanted part of the plot

gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, xlocs=range(-150,180,30), ylocs=range(0, 90, 15), 
                  y_inline=True, linestyle='--', lw= 5, color= "w", )

# Get limits, the values are the radius of the circular map extent
# The values is then used as r = 5476336.09797 on top of the code
#print(ax.get_xlim())
#print(ax.get_ylim())

plt.show()
```

[image: nhemis]